# Rotation of the translational component of a Matrix

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es, rotational-matrices

Using the android.graphics.Matrix library:

```
Matrix foo = new Matrix();

foo.setTranslate(10.0f, 0.0f);
Log.d("MatrixTest", foo.toString());

foo.postRotate(30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Log.d("MatrixTest", foo.toString());
```

I obtain the following output:

```
foo = {[1.0, 0.0, 10.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
foo = {[0.8660254, -0.5, 8.660254][0.5, 0.8660254, 5.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
```

Which is precisely what I would expect.

It would now be useful for my application to also run on the desktop, so I am porting to libgdx.

Using the com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix3 library:

```
Matrix3 bar = new Matrix3();

bar.translate(10.0f, 0.0f);
System.out.println(bar.toString());

bar.rotate(30.0f);
System.out.println(bar.toString());
```

I obtain the following output:

```
bar = [1.0|0.0|10.0] [0.0|1.0|0.0] [0.0|0.0|1.0]
bar = [0.8660254|-0.5|10.0] [0.5|0.8660254|0.0] [0.0|0.0|1.0]
```

In this case, the translation component of X has not been rotated.

Is this the correct behaviour?  The API for both the android postRotate() method and the libgdx rotate() method describe them as a post-rotate functions.

I get similar results for libgdx Matrix4, which is what I would actually like to use.

Can someone suggest a nice way to reproduce the results obtained from the android library using libgdx Matrix3 or 4?

Comment: I think swapping the operations should do what you are looking for. So first rotate and then translate. If this is the case I will explain in a bit more in detail in the answer.

Comment: You are right of course.  I understand that matrix multiplication is not commutative.  But since both APIs advertise themselves as being postMultiply the frustrating thing is that they do not produce the same result!

Comment: Well the second one seems to use standard operations so either the documentation is wrong or it is missinterpreted.

Comment: Misinterpreted on my part, I'm confusing which matrix is being post-concatentated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get things clear...

It is least ambiguous if you just stick to matrix multiplication then trying to use convenience methods to use the operations on the matrix themselves.

In most cases when doing an operation on the matrix such as translate what will happen is a translation matrix will be created and the original matrix will be multiplied by the new matrix as `originalMatrix*translationMatrix`. This is what happens in your second example. Your first example has a prefix "post" which seems to do the invers operation `translationMatrix*originalMatrix`.

I can understand this "post" may be useful and for someone who is not very familiar with matrix operations it may even be more natural to use. What I can not understand is "postMultiply". This is not how it works at all, this is not how the matrix multiplication is used and will only confuse most of the developers. Not only in the process of learning but even if later someone will read this code. Sure it works but to me this would be the same as writing something like this:

Print first `N` integer values:

```
    for(int i=N; i>0; --i)
    {
        int printValue = N-i+1;
        // print the printValue
    }
```

Sure this works but for me it is totally unreadable.

If in any case you have trouble imagining matrix multiplication you should think of it as if you would be looking at it from the first person. For instance translate in X axis would mean step forward, Y left and Z up. The rotations are then only around your center and will never effect your position.

So in first example you first rotate towards your left for 30 degrees and you are now facing toward point `(0.8660254, 0.5)`. Then you translate by 10 along X axis which means step forward for 10 points and your position becomes `(0.8660254, 0.5)*10.0` so you end up at `(8.660254, 5.0)` facing towards `(8.660254 + 0.8660254, 5.0 + 0.5)`.

In the second example you first translate by 10 points along X axis which means go forward by 10 points ending at `(10, 0)` still facing the same direction and then you rotate by 30 degrees to your left and simply end up at the same location at `(10.0, .0)` facing toward `(10.0+0.8660254, .0+.5)`.

As you can now probably see from the results you are getting the columns in your matrix (not the rows in your case) define the matrix base vectors. So simply from those vectors you can understand which way the object is facing and where is it's center. You may also simply construct a matrix from those vectors. If you want to create a matrix for an object which is at position `P` and is faced in the direction `D` then the matrix is:

```
D.x, D.y, .0
-D.y, D.x, .0
P.x, P.y, 1.0
```

In your case transposed

```
D.x, -D.y, P.x
D.y, D.x, P.y
.0, .0, 1.0
```